# show_comments=false in player widget disables link to sound

Tags: widget, soundcloud

With the following code the link to the sound on Soundcloud in the bottom right corner of the widget works (Firefox/OSX):

```
<iframe id="sc-widget" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/k0s/bcn07" width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
<script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it stops working when I add `show_comments=false` as a query parameter:

```
<iframe id="sc-widget" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/k0s/bcn07&show_comments=false" width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
<script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug in the widget -- the container for the comments was still being added to the page and it was covering the link. I've pushed a fix to it now and you should see it fixed within a few minutes.

Also, the `url` parameter should point to the API endpoint: eg:

Instead of

```
.../player/?url=http://soundclou...
```

It should be:

```
.../player/?url=http://api.soundclou...
```